# AWS EC2 instance creating database and uploading pages

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Hi guys yesterday I was fiddling with AWS EC2 and successfully created an instance i remotely accessed the linux based ubuntu instance through mind term nd installed apache 2,mysql and phpmyadmin........

i was thinking of uploading my website there and pages in the ../var/www/html folder so is it wise to store webpages there or should i use s3 bucket and connect them??....

i think if i upload pages there it will be accessed faster there and also if i created databases there it will be faster to access instead of connecting them through AWS RDS I watched this tutorial of andrew puch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz-4wTGD2_Q this helped me a lot with creation and connecting the instance with RDS....
So to sum up

1. should i create databases on the server or on AWS RDS which will be faster
2. should i upload my website in the above mentioned folder or connect through s3 bucket???
3. and the last if i want to do all this on the EC2 instance server how to can i gain permission for uploading and creating database and     tables throught php scripts and also to upload files and folder in     that var/www/html folder through WINSCP.....

thanks for the help guys really appreciate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Creating the database directly on the server may be faster (depends
   on several things), but you'll lose *all* your data if the server
   terminates for whatever reason! I strongly recommend separating it, except maybe for test environments.
2. As you want to use PHP (if I guessed correctly), you won't be able
   to host your pages on S3. You'll need a server for that (which you
   have now).
3. Look into
   https://superuser.com/questions/286831/how-do-i-copy-files-into-var-www-with-winscp
   for copying files with WinSCP and how to set the permissions on your
   server.

Comment: 1.so i should use RDS service right? 2.and upload pages on the var www html folder 3.thanks for the link i will try changing ownership..

Comment: @user287332 1. correct, it's safer, especially for production environments, 2. correct, 3. correct

Comment: Generally speaking, never consider a EC2 instance to really be persistent. Virtual machines come and go, you may want to add an ELB later with an auto scaling groups, etc. It's always safe to assume not to store any data on a EC2 instance and use dedicated services for it (e.g. S3, RDS, etc.)